# Cannot update picture but getting 200 status

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I would like to update a profile picture. The problem is when I send the image through axios to my server I get a `200` message. However, the profile picture is not updated.

I know the issue has something to do with my frontend code because when it try to upload a picture using Postman, the image is correctly updated.

This is the code I am using to send the image:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let profileData = new FormData()
  profileData.append('profilePic', {
    uri: fileDataURL,
    type: 'multipart/form-data',
    name: 'profile_pic.png',
  });
  updateProfilePic(profileData, updatedProfileInfo.user_id)
}
```

and the axios request sending the image to the server:

```
const updateProfilePic = (profilePicData, user_id) => {
  console.log('formData contains', ...profilePicData)
  const headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
  }
  const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_profile/' 
  axios.patch(`${base_url}${user_id}/`,profilePicData, {
    headers,
  })
  .then( res => {
    console.log('resp', res)
  })
}
```

This is what I have in fileDataURL:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/...
```

In a nutshell I know that everything that happens before the code I have shown is working, I upload a picture, I get the image base64 string and append that to profileData

Comment: Where is `fileDataURL` coming from?

Comment: 200 status doesn't mean the operation succeeded, just that the http request was ok.

Comment: @Terry I added an additional line to the question to give you more context. I get fileDataURL when I update a profile picture in the front end

Comment: @evolutionxbox Ok. My point is I can update the picture in Postman. I know the picture is getting updated, but I am only getting a status 200 when I try and replicate this using the code I included in the question